# How to find out the list of repos one has been access to?

Tags: git

**Is there a way to find out names of all repos one has access to on a server?**

I moved my dev box to Mac from a PC and did not copy the names of repos to clone.

No big deal, just wondering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is not a way to do that built into git itself. Systems that wrap git, like github, gitolite or gitosis have ways that track that kind of information.